# How to remove fields from json in go?

Tags: go

I've this struct in my code.

```
type AppVersion struct {
    Id            int64     `json:"id"`
    App           App       `json:"app,omitempty" out:"false"`
    AppId         int64     `sql:"not null" json:"app_id"`
    Version       string    `sql:"not null" json:"version"`
    Sessions      []Session `json:"-"`
    SessionsCount int       `sql:"-"`
    CreatedAt     time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt     time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt     time.Time `json:"deleted_at"`
}
```

I'm building a webservice and I don't need to send the `App` field in the JSON.
I've tried a few things to remove the field from the JSON but I haven't been able to do it.

How can I achieve this?
Is there any way to set struct as empty?

I'm using GORM as database access layer, so I'm not sure if I can do `App *App`, do you know if it will work?

Comment: Have you tried it? I suspect it will work.

Comment: I've tried and it doesn't work, there's a problem with database creation / migration

Comment: Well, that sounds like a problem with GORM. You could implement your own `json.Marshaler` and `json.Unmarshaler` on `AppVersion` if you want to further control serialization outside of the spec of the `json` package.

Comment: I'm quite new to go, how can I create my custom Marshaler?

Comment: you implement `MarshalJSON` and `UnmarshalJSON` on `AppVersion`. The `json` package will call those methods if they exists instead of using its own reflection based marshaling.

Answer (score 2):

```
type AppVersion struct {
    Id            int64     `json:"id"`
    App           App       `json:"-"`
    AppId         int64     `sql:"not null" json:"app_id"`
    Version       string    `sql:"not null" json:"version"`
    Sessions      []Session `json:"-"`
    SessionsCount int       `sql:"-"`
    CreatedAt     time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt     time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt     time.Time `json:"deleted_at"`
}
```

More info - [json-go](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to wrap your data structure into a custom type which hides the app field:

```
type ExportAppVersion struct {
   AppVersion
   App `json:"-"`
}
```

This should hide the `App` field from being exposed.

Comment: The problem os setting the json:"-" is that then I miss the field when decoding the json.

Comment: Also I would like to have the option to control when I want to send it back or not.

Comment: Don't wrap it in this struct if you want to deserialize / send it.